# Build existing C++ solution on linux using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, remote-debugging

I have have a CMake project, which I sometimes I need to build/debug on Linux. I've tried using "Linux development with C++" to connect to my Virtual Debian machine, but it doesn't work the way I want.

It don't want to create a new project, I only want to generate a makefile using CMake and connect to it.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/11/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/

I've tried to read this, but it doen't tell how to connect to an existing project.

Comment: if you project is based on CMake, why don't you just build it on linux using CMake?

Comment: Well, I do build in on linux using CMake. I need to make it useful for people who are not familiar with linux.

Answer (score 1):

> I only want to generate a makefile using CMake

You can check out in Properties->General->Project Defaults->Configuration type to use existing makefile.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/cmake-linux-project?view=vs-2017) microsoft gives you nice guide on how to make use CMakeLists.txt file in Visual Studio 2017.

In short you need to

- Open your CMakeLists.txt and source files(No need to create new project for this, just do open folder)
- Choose Linux target in Tools > Options > Cross Platform > Connection Manager
- Configure CMake settings for Linux by right-clicking CMakeSettings.txt in Solution Explorer and choose Change CMake Settings. It is saved as a CMakeSettings.json file in your project folder

When building, the source files on your development PC are copied to the Linux computer and compiled there.

Please not that it requires Visual Studio 2017 **version 15.4 and later**.
Also, CMake support in Visual Studio requires the server mode support that was introduced in **CMake 3.8**. You can get Microsoft provided CMake from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CMake/releases)

Comment: @miradham, thanks, but is there a way to compile from a generated makefile?

Comment: Sometimes I need to compile just a few libs, but not the whole solution. It would be much easier to compile the makefile.

Comment: @EugeneMart have you tried to change Configuration type in Project defaults?